# Dart extention is doing pub get automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, dart-pub

`Flutter Pub get` automatically pops-up and start getting packages. After finishing, it **starts again** doing the same.

Like we save *pubspac.yaml* in `vscode` then dart plugin automatically *runs Flutter pub get* automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

my answer in vs code
steps:

1. open extension   (ctrl + shift + x)
2. open dart extension
3. click on the setting icon next to uninstall button
4. click on extension settings in the menu
5. search pub get
6. Dart: Run Pub Get On Pubspec Changes : make it never

Answer (score 2):

It runs automatically when there are changes on the `pubspec.yaml` file to retrieve dependencies that are added (assuming you saved the file **after**). @ahmed's answer should prevent VS Code from doing it automatically:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :** I think you have keep open the pubspec.yaml on vscode, that is why it's keep performing pub get again & again.

**Solution :** You can close the pubspec.yaml after editing it.

Comment: yes, pubspac.yaml file is reason for this rare issue.

Comment: but this problem occours sometimes without pubspac.yaml file opend

Comment: In that case you can reload the vs-code